# What is the meaning of ngrx adapter selector syntax?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I have found following example of ngrx adapter:

```
export const {
  selectAll: selectAllItems
} = adapter.getSelectors<State>(state => state.items);
```

But I don't understand what is assigned to what here.
Especially the notation of a type:
`const {sth: foo} = bar;`
Would someone be so nice, to advise me, please :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the syntax for [Object Destruction in Typescript](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/destructuring.html) and assigning to new variable names:

Your code roughly translates to classic javascript as ([parsed using online parser](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20selectAll%3A%20selectAllItems%0D%0A%7D%20%3D%20adapter.getSelectors%3CState%3E(state%20%3D%3E%20state.items)%3B)):

```
const selectAllItems = adapter.getSelectors(state => state.items).selectAll;
```

Another example copied from TS Docs:

```
// structure
const obj = {"some property": "some value"};

// destructure
const {"some property": someProperty} = obj;
console.log(someProperty === "some value"); // true
```

This is akin to [Object destruction in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names) like:

```
const {x, y} = {x: 10, y: 20};
console.log(x, y); // 10 20
```

Or a property can be unpacked from an object and assigned to a variable with a different name than the object property. (From MDN Docs)

```
var o = {p: 42, q: true};
var {p: foo, q: bar} = o;

console.log(foo); // 42 
console.log(bar); // true
```

Here, for example, `var {p: foo} = o` takes from the object o the property named p and assigns it to a local variable named foo.

Comment: Destructuring objects is not specific to TS, it's just modern Javascript. So it doesn't "translate to JS" as much as it's just the equivalent of it (although it's not really equivalent since your code doesn't export anything)

Comment: @IngoBürk Do javascript support deep object destruction like this? Never seen a spec on that. Yeah, *translate* just shows my inefficient English language command :)

Comment: This is just destructuring an object and renaming the key as we do so, and yes this is supported in modern JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names